# user model password field default password field in django

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I've created a custom user model in my application. This user model is working fine, but there
are a couple of problems I have with it.

1. The change password link in the my register.html page doesn't work?
2. The default password box on the add/edit page for a user is a
   little unfriendly.

Ideally, what I'd like is the two password fields
from the change password form on the add/edit user form in the admin,
which will automatically turn convert the entered password into a
valid encrypted password in Django.
This would make the admin system MUCH friendlier and much more suited
to my needs, as a fair number of user accounts will be created and
maintained manually in this app, and the person responsible for doing
so will likely be scared off at the sight of that admin field, or just
type a clear text password and wonder why it doesn't work.
Is this possible / How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own view for editing user, or try to customize admin template for user.